# Pattern expansion to run commands

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

Knowing I am able to run `echo` or `mv` to expand patterns like these: `echo {0..9}{A..Z}`. I am curious to know if there is a way to do the same but to run commands?

```
docker-compose {stop,rm,up -d}
```

The example above does not work, but there is some way to accomplish that (to run stop, rm and up separately)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `eval`:

```
eval docker-compose\ {stop,rm,'up -d'}\;
```

Careful escaping/quoting is needed, though. Just test with `echo` instead of `docker` that it emits the correct commands:

```
$ echo docker-compose\ {stop,rm,'up -d'}\;
docker-compose stop; docker-compose rm; docker-compose up -d;
```

Comment: You can also quote instead of escaping

Answer (score 5):

Not the way you mention it.

[Brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) occurs before any other expansion. This means that when you say `echo {0,1}{a,b}`, Bash expands the braces before going through any other step. This way, it becomes `echo 0a 0b 1a 1b`, **a single command**.

When you mention `docker-compose {stop,rm,up -d}`, note this would expand to a single command: `docker-compose stop rm up -d`, which doesn't seem to be valid.

It looks like you would like to run **three different commands**:

```
docker-compose stop
docker-compose rm
docker-compose up -d
```

For this, you may want to use a loop (note "up -d" is quoted so that it is treated as a single argument):

```
for argument in stop rm "up -d"
do
    docker-compose $argument
done
```

Comment: Note that quoting is only necessary for `"up -d"` otherwise it would be two words.

Comment: Also note that `"$parameter"` is almost certainly *wrong* as the docker will receive a single argument `up -d`... Just get rid of the quotes.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath not sure if there is a difference between `docker-compose "up -d"` and `docker compose up -d`.

Comment: There's a huge difference, one receives just 1 argument the other 2. Anything that is using standard argument parsing techniques (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash so pretty much anything) will fail on `"up -d"`.